# ContentDialog: Applying both Style and PrimaryButtonStyle

Tags: xaml, uwp

Gang,

I'm referencing the 16299 version.

I'm trying to set a style for the ContentDialog, and a Style for the PrimaryButton. However, I cannot get both of them working together:

```
<ContentDialog x:Class="App1.ContentDialog1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
  SecondaryButtonText="Button2" 
  Style="{StaticResource ContentDialogStyle}" 
  PrimaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource ContentDialogPrimaryButtonStyle}">
    <Grid />
</ContentDialog>
```

This will only apply the "Style" and not the "PrimaryButtonStyle". However, if I remove the "Style" attribute, I then get the PrimaryButtonStyle applied.

I have tried applying the PimaryButtonStyle inside the Style XAML, but that doesn't work either:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ContentDialogPrimaryButtonStyle">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      ...
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ContentDialog" x:Key="ContentDialogStyle">
  <Setter Property="PrimaryButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource ContentDialogPrimaryButtonStyle}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      ...
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any ideas how I style the Primary/Secondary buttons inside a ContentDialog that itself has a Style?

Kind regards

Adam

Comment: Are you overriding the template with your own buttons?

Comment: Yeah, trying to.

Comment: If you're overriding the template you could just use your own buttons with whatever styles you want the same ways you can any normal button. :)

Comment: I've been doing that so far, but facing a whole load of focus issues with my own template (on the xbox). Seeming as the ContentDialog has Primary & Secondary buttons, and has a property to set their styles, I want to use as native an approach as possible. Setting the styles works fine if I don't style the ContentDialog, but get's ignored if I do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be related with your `Template` in the `ContentDialogStyle`. We can change both `ContentDialogStyle` and `PrimaryButtonStyle` in the xaml, here is a simple example, you can see it. Then you should take a look at your `Template` in the `ContentDialogStyle`.

This is the code,

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ContentDialogPrimaryButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5">
                    <ContentPresenter Background="Red" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ContentDialog" x:Key="ContentDialogStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>
```

This is the ContentDialog,

```
<ContentDialog
    ...
    PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
    SecondaryButtonText="Button2"
    Style="{StaticResource ContentDialogStyle}"
    PrimaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource ContentDialogPrimaryButtonStyle}">

    <Grid/>

</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: But in this scenario we aren't overriding the Template on the ContentDialog, which I need to do. I need to set the template to a custom template for both the ContentDialog and the PrimaryButton.

Comment: I can set the PrimaryButton style inside the ContentDialog Template directly, but this defeats the purpose of having the PrimaryButtonStyle on the ContentDialog, as it's not hard baked into the style of the ContentDialog.        <Border x:Name="Button1Host">
                                                <Border.Resources>
                                                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ContentDialogPrimaryButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
                                                </Border.Resources>
                                            </Border>

Comment: My above code is just a sample to clarify that we can change both style, for your this issue, you should look into your custom template of the `ContentDialog` . In short , for example, if your ContentDialog custom template don't have a PrimaryButton or the PrimaryButton is totally different, the PrimaryButtonStyle property should not work for it.

Comment: Both the Styles I've lifted directly from MSDN, so the templates are identical (aside from a colour change to test if the style is being applied).

Comment: You have targeted the app on 16299, you can find the default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog has been changed with this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx), you can find the corresponding ContentDialog style in the generic.xaml file which should be in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.16299.0\Generic. With this template, you should can use the PrimaryButtonStyle property.

Comment: Dude, that's it :) I was using the template from MSDN and not the Generic.xaml.